# Libnoise producing completely random noise

Tags: c++, algorithm, perlin-noise

I am using [libnoise](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/) in C++ taken and I have some problems with getting coherent noise. I mean, the noise produced now are completely random and it doesn't look like a noise.

Here's the image produced by my game.

[image]

I am dividing the map into several chunks, but I can't seem to find any problem doing that since libnoise supports tileable noise. The code can be found below.

Every chunk is 8x8 tiles large. Every tile is 64x64 pixels.

This is the code for generating a chunk

```
 Chunk *World::loadChunk(sf::Vector2i pPosition)
 {
     sf::Vector2i chunkPos = pPosition;
     pPosition.x *= mChunkTileSize.x;
     pPosition.y *= mChunkTileSize.y;
     sf::FloatRect bounds(static_cast<sf::Vector2f>(pPosition), sf::Vector2f(static_cast<float>(mChunkTileSize.x), static_cast<float>(mChunkTileSize.y)));

     utils::NoiseMap heightMap;
     utils::NoiseMapBuilderPlane heightMapBuilder;
     heightMapBuilder.SetSourceModule(mNoiseModule);
     heightMapBuilder.SetDestNoiseMap(heightMap);
     heightMapBuilder.SetDestSize(mChunkTileSize.x, mChunkTileSize.y);
     heightMapBuilder.SetBounds(bounds.left, bounds.left + bounds.width - 1, bounds.top, bounds.top + bounds.height - 1);
     heightMapBuilder.Build();

     Chunk *chunk = new Chunk(this);
     chunk->setPosition(chunkPos);
     chunk->buildChunk(&heightMap);
     chunk->setTexture(&mTileset);
     mChunks.push_back(chunk);
     return chunk;
 }
```

This is the code for building the chunk

```
void Chunk::buildChunk(utils::NoiseMap *pHeightMap)
{
    // Resize the tiles space
    mTiles.resize(pHeightMap->GetWidth());
    for (int x = 0; x < mTiles.size(); x++)
    {
        mTiles[x].resize(pHeightMap->GetHeight());
    }

    // Set vertices type and size
    mVertices.setPrimitiveType(sf::Quads);
    mVertices.resize(pHeightMap->GetWidth() * pHeightMap->GetWidth() * 4);

    // Get the offset position of all tiles position
    sf::Vector2i tileSize = mWorld->getTileSize();
    sf::Vector2i chunkSize = mWorld->getChunkSize();
    sf::Vector2f offsetPositon = sf::Vector2f(mPosition);
    offsetPositon.x *= chunkSize.x;
    offsetPositon.y *= chunkSize.y;

    // Build tiles
    for (int x = 0; x < mTiles.size(); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < mTiles[x].size(); y++)
        {
            // Sometimes libnoise can return a value over 1.0, better be sure to cap the top and bottom..
            float heightValue = pHeightMap->GetValue(x, y);
            if (heightValue > 1.f) heightValue = 1.f;
            if (heightValue < -1.f) heightValue = -1.f;

            // Instantiate a new Tile object with the noise value, this doesn't do anything yet..
            mTiles[x][y] = new Tile(this, pHeightMap->GetValue(x, y));

            // Get a pointer to the current tile's quad
            sf::Vertex *quad = &mVertices[(y + x * pHeightMap->GetWidth()) * 4];

            quad[0].position = sf::Vector2f(offsetPositon.x + x * tileSize.x, offsetPositon.y + y * tileSize.y);
            quad[1].position = sf::Vector2f(offsetPositon.x + (x + 1) * tileSize.x, offsetPositon.y + y * tileSize.y);
            quad[2].position = sf::Vector2f(offsetPositon.x + (x + 1) * tileSize.x, offsetPositon.y + (y + 1) * tileSize.y);
            quad[3].position = sf::Vector2f(offsetPositon.x + x * tileSize.x, offsetPositon.y + (y + 1) * tileSize.y);

            // find out which type of tile to render, atm only air or stone
            TileStop *tilestop = mWorld->getTileStopAt(heightValue);
            sf::Vector2i texturePos = tilestop->getTexturePosition();

            // define its 4 texture coordinates
            quad[0].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(texturePos.x, texturePos.y);
            quad[1].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(texturePos.x + 64, texturePos.y);
            quad[2].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(texturePos.x + 64, texturePos.y + 64);
            quad[3].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(texturePos.x, texturePos.y + 64);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably the noise frequency is too high.

Comment: Are you **sure** that libnoise returns >1.0 values?  Something smells wrong there, the range should be from -1.0 .. +1.0

Comment: @PatrickHughes I saw that som values was > 1.0, some of them was 1.1xxxx so I'm sure it's not a floating point bug.

Comment: @NathanReed Yea, that is actually the problem. Such stupid problem.